# Why is my coroutine code not functioning properly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been attempting to write some code that will make the "Game Over" screen in my unity game appear after 3 seconds have passed.  How ever, whenever I try to utilize a coroutine that counts 3 seconds of game time, the Game Over screen just ends up not appearing at all and the game continues to run after the player object is destroyed.  The code that calls the Game Over screen function is in the Player script; I have made sure that the correct game object is being referenced in the unity editor.  The Game Over screen works fine if I just call it like this:

```
public void GameOver()
    {

        explosionController.StartExplosion(transform.position);

        particleJumpTrigger.DisableParticleSystem();
        Destroy(gameObject);

        gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);

    }
```

However, when I change the code, the game over screen doesn't appear at all:

```
//This function sets a wait time for the Game Over screen to appear after the player dies
    public IEnumerator GameOverScreen()
    {
        float countdownTime = 0f;

        while (countdownTime < 3.0f)
        {
            countdownTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null; // Wait for the next frame
        }

        gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
    }


    //This function is called when the player collides with a different color, destroying the player object
    public void GameOver()
    {

        explosionController.StartExplosion(transform.position);

        particleJumpTrigger.DisableParticleSystem();
        Destroy(gameObject);

        GameOverScreen();

    }
```

I've tried making functions that count to 3 seconds in other ways, but none of my ideas seem to fix the problem.  I'm kinda out of ideas at this point and need some external guidance on what to do.

Comment: Use [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html), use [`StartCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Comment: Why don't you use `WaitForSeconds` function?

Answer (score 1):

You *must* use `StartCoroutine` to start any coroutine. Change your call to `GameOverScreen` to `StartCoroutine(GameOverScreen())`.

```
public void GameOver()
{
   explosionController.StartExplosion(transform.position);

   particleJumpTrigger.DisableParticleSystem();
   Destroy(gameObject);

   StartCoroutine(GameOverScreen());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public IEnumerator GameOverScreen()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
}
```

Also to IEnumerator should be called with `StartCoroutine`:

```cs
StartCoroutine(GameOverScreen());
```

If you don't know about `Coroutines` watch this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L9ksCs6MbE

Comment: I used your exact code, and the Game Over screen still fails to appear.  I implemented the following code in my Player Script:

`public IEnumerator GameOverScreen()
    {
        Debug.Log("Notification");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);

        Debug.Log("I WAITED");

        gameOverScreen.SetActive(true);
    }`


What's weird is that the `Debug.Log("Notification");` gets called and I see it in the console in unity, but the `Debug.Log("I WAITED");` line never gets called.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  I was writing this code inside my Player Script, which was being destroyed along with the Player Object in my scene, so the coroutine could never actually complete!  I fixed this by creating a separate script to manage the Game Over screen, and now it works perfectly.  Thank you for all of your help anyway!